I have tokens in my Solana account on my brave wallet, I want to move them
I see FIDA (Bonifida) in the wallet, the other tokens I can only see in Solana explorer under token holdings. I do not not what to do with the Mint address or how to move the token to another wallet or to an exchange so that I can see them if I want.
